# Wear signed apk doesn't contains data?

Tags: android, wear-os, signed-apk

I am newbie with wear app..
I have generated signed release apk for both :mobile and :wear apk .I have no issues with :mobile apk but my :wear apk is not containing any data.
when after generating apk, i got below error when i look in edit configuration for wear module.I tried to fix it for multiple times by providing all details in signing tab..but unable to fix it.

> The apk for your currently selected variant
>   (wear-release-unsigned.apk)is not signed. Please specify a signing
>   configuration for this variant(release).

so i checked the wear-release.apk file i see their is no data in my wear apk..
how to fix this ???...please help..!!!!

Error in Message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':wear:packageRelease'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidMWear1 from store
> >     "C:\Users\abhi.AndroidStudio2.2\system\androidmwear.jks": No key with
> >     alias 'AndroidMWear1' found in keystore
> >     C:\Users\abhi.AndroidStudio2.2\system\androidmwear.jks

I looked into other questions on stack overflow related to this issue and wear issues but none solved my issue so i am posting this...

**Edit 1:**

Apk data issued solved by creating two different keystores for both the apk ..but still having  below issue

> The apk for your currently selected variant
>   (wear-release-unsigned.apk)is not signed. Please specify a signing
>   configuration for this variant(release).

**Edit 2:**
Check all information in signing tab its same as defined for wear-release.apk...but still asking to specify singning configuration..

[image: wear apk]

Comment: Tried deleting apk..and creating again but it doesn't help...???

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared any of your codes, you may want to check and make sure that you have properly packaged your wearable app. It's noted in [Packaging Wearable Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) that,

> **This feature doesn't work when you are signing your apps with a debug key when developing. While developing, installing apps with adb install or Android Studio directly to the wearable is required.**

So if you're using Android Studio, here's how to properly package a wearable app: (If you haven't done so, you may try doing these.)

> 1. Include all the permissions declared in the manifest file of the wearable app module in the manifest file of the handheld app module. For example, if you specify the VIBRATE permission for the wearable app, you must also add that permission to the handheld app.
> 2. Ensure that both the wearable and handheld app modules have the same package name and version number.
> 3. Declare a Gradle dependency in the handheld app's build.gradle file that points to the wearable app module:
>
>    `dependencies {
>         compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+@aar'
>         compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+''
>         wearApp project(':wearable')
>      }`
> 4. Click **Build > Generate Signed APK**... and follow the on-screen instructions to specify your release keystore and sign your app. Android Studio exports the signed handheld app with the wearable app embedded in it automatically into your project's root folder.

Then, you can sign your wearable and handheld app separately.

> If your build process requires signing the wearable app separately from the handheld app, you can declare the following Gradle rule in the handheld module's `build.gradle` to embed the previously-signed wearable app:
>
> `dependencies {
>         ...
>         wearApp files('/path/to/wearable_app.apk')`
>   }`

Going through [App Distribution](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/app-distribution.html) might also help.

Comment: I checked all details you mentioned in your answer already..but still no success...I tried creating wear apk again with different keystore for both modules.. i guess that was one of the issue why i was not having data in wear apk but this time I am having data but error is still their The apk for your currently selected variant (wear-release-unsigned.apk)is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant(release).???Can you help me with this thing??